# properties or variable, which one is better for class?

Tags: php, class, variables

I have a question in my mind.
I can pass a variable to a class by an argument of class method:

```
<?php
$val = 'My name';
include('myClass.php');
newClass = new myClass();
newClass->test($val);
?>

<?php
class myClass{
private $myVal;
  public function test($val){
    $this->myVal = $val;
    $this->showName();
  }

  private function showName(){
    echo $this-> $myVal;
  }
 }
?>
```

or I can send the variable as class properties.

```
<?php
include('myClass.php');
newClass = new myClass();
newClass->$myVal='My name';
newClass->test();
?>

<?php
class myClass{
public $myVal;
  public function test(){
    $this->showName();
  }

  private function showName(){
    echo $this-> $myVal;
  }
 }
?>
```

Although in both case, output is same and this is a very simple example, but for large chunk of codes, which one is better in terms of memory usage, cpu usages, I/O usage etc. Large chunk of codes means suppose a large javascript code paased as argument written by heredoc or passed as a public property of that class.

Comment: I would not be worry about cpu usages/ I/O usages etc. It is 2015! The more important point is not to break the OOP rules.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use private/protected properties and getters and setters. If variable is required for class to work pass it as constructor argument

```
   class MyClass
   {

    private $myVal;

    public function __construct($myVal)
    {
       $this->setMyVal($myVal);
    }

    public function getMyVal()
    {
      return $this->myVal;
    }

    public function setMyVal($myVal)
    {
       $this->myVal = $myVal;

       return $this;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
$obj = new MyClass(5);
echo $obj->getMyVal();
```

When using getters/setters you have more control of variables being set/get you can add validation, truncation etc. to setters and you for example format getters or add some conditions(Example would be DateTime you may want to get DateTime as string formated according to locale but you want set DateTime object);